# SQL query correction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two following tables

Table Prize

[image]

Table Entry

[image]

All I need to do is List `event_id`, `horse_id`, place and prize money for each entry. I executed the following query to do so but I'm not getting accurate Prizemoney.

```
SELECT entry.event_id,entry.horse_id, entry.place, prize.prizemoney 


FROM entry


LEFT OUTER JOIN prize ON prize.event_code=entry.event_id
GROUP BY event_id, horse_id;
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Can you specify why the **Prizemoney** is not accurate? What is off about the values being returned?

Comment: I don't understand the logic by which you arrived at the prize money values in your expected output.

Comment: As you can see the prize money for event 0101 for PLACE 2 is suppose to be 60 but I got 120 in my result.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Tim, I just want to add correct prize money to the entry table, to which I used Left Join.

Comment: The group by seems redundant here - did you have a reason for grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `event_id` is not truly unique by itself- there are multiple rows that have the same event_id. What you actually appear to have is a composite key (with `event_id` and `place`) defining a unique entry. So when you join only on `event_id`, MySQL is not sure which value of prize money to return. For example, for event_id = 101, there are four different values (`120, 60, 30, 10`) that should be returned.

**Edit:** LEFT JOIN on both `event_id` and `place`:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN prize ON prize.event_code=entry.event_id AND prize.place = entry.place
```

**Original answer:** If you haven't created a primary key constraint yet for your prize money table (Table Prize) and your Table Entry, you'll need to do so: **Event ID 101, 1st place** should get its own primary key, **Event ID 101, 2nd place** its own primary key, etc. Then join on the primary keys to get the correct result in your Output table.

Comment: Thank You very much Yu Chen :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select e.event_id, e.horse_id, e.place, p.prizemoney
  from entry e
left join prize p on p.event_code = e.event_id AND e.place = p.place
```